# Why a positive recurrent Markov chain implies positive limiting probability?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X=\{X_0,X_1,\ldots\}$ be an irreducible, positive recurrent, and aperiodic Markov chain with the state space $S=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ then how do we show that the probability 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n=k\mid X_0=j)
$$
is independent of $j$ and strictly positive? That is, why
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n=k\mid X_0=j)=g(k)>0?
$$

Comment: You need the Markov chain to be irreducible and aperiodic, not just positive recurrent.

Comment: @ Robert: You are absolutely right. I forgot to mention that in my question but now I add this assumption too. Thanks!

Comment: @Inj You really need it to be aperiodic as well, otherwise the limit may not exist.

Comment: @ Sasha: Yes, that's true.